# Redirect User After Login in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement my login page, so it can redirect to specific page in the websites. When the user click on the Login, it check if the user is staff, then send the user to admin page, not user then stay at login, if regular user, then send to regular user page. I haven't completed the LoginView yet because I just want to see if it can direct to admin page after login. I have researched online and tried many different way, but I couldn't figure out how to do so.  What should I change or add in the urls.py or LOGIN_URL/LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. Thank you!

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('output/', views.output, name="output"),
    path('default_crawler/', views.default_page, name="default_page"),
    path('admin_page/', views.admin_page, name="admin_page"),
    path('regular_page/', views.regular_page, name="regular_page"),
    path('pass_forgot/', views.pass_forgot, name="pass_forgot"),
    path('pass_change/', views.pass_change, name="pass_change"),
    path('pass_change_success/', views.pass_change_success,
         name="pass_change_success"),
    path('pass_found/', views.pass_found, name="pass_found"),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name="register"),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def LoginView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user.is_staff:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('admin_page')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_URL
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

`LOGIN_URL` is the setting used to redirect users to the login page when, for instance, the `login_required()` decorator is used.

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is used for redirecting users after a successful login attempt.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

However, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` only allows for one redirect URL, so for your use case I would advice to set it separately in the login view instead. *However*, this omits the functionality of using the `next` parameter in your requests, so be aware that this is a tradeoff unless you specifically adds it.

Comment: I'm pretty new to django, and I don't much about it. Where and How should I change the LoginView so it can redirect to page that I mentioned in the post?

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to rediretc after login/logout in django:

**1.**
You can redirect after login/logout in html templates. You just need to use the `next` parametr as follow:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}          
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={% url 'app_name:after_logout' %}">{{ some_username }}</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={% url 'app_name:admin_page' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

So, if your staff is admin you will go to `admin_page` ('admin_page/')
If you want to logout, you will go to page with name  `after_logout` (I just made it up)

**Or**

**2.**
You need to add to settings.py

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'after_logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'admin_page/'
```